# Handwriting recognition in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight

I need to extract text from images in a Silverlight application. The app is an elevated out-of-browser app so I am free to use any library or COM API. Is there a way or library to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the [Aforge.NET](http://www.aforgenet.com/) for working with my image/gesture recognition app modules. It has a nice well-documented API. You might need a combination of the neuro and imaging APIs. Also have a look at  [NeuronDotNet](http://neurondotnet.freehostia.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I'm just working on doing handwriting recognition and I'm using the Tablet PC / Ink APIs from Microsoft. You can access them via COM from Silverlight - I got that bit working. The good thing here is that there is nothing to deploy, which would be difficult with Silverlight. But it will only work for you if you have strokes (paths) rather than pure images.